# How to set jquery variable in PHP CURL

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, variables, get

I have a screen scrape code in PHP like this:

```
<?
$url = 'https://www.google.nl/search?q=cars';
$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$curl_scraped_page = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
echo $curl_scraped_page;
?>
```

I also have a Jquery(ajax) script which can fetch the proxy like this:

```
$.get('ThePhpFile.php', function(data){

     $(data).appendTo('div')

}
```

Everything is working fine, but now I would like to set the URL to be scraped as a variable which is in fact the value of some input in parent document (I'm working with iframes). I know how to do this in Jquery:

```
var TheUrl = $("input", parent.document.body).val();
```

So my question is how do I set the variable to work with the PHP code. Is it necessary to put it in the PHP code? How do I do that?

Comment: You need to ajax the variable to the php

Comment: @mplungjan I already tried several things but with no luck(not good at PHP) If I Google I only encounter codes which go in the opposite direction PHP variable ----> Jquery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to ajax the variable to the php:

This will send ?url=..... to the php

Full example [DEMO](http://plungjan.name/SO/searchproxy.html)

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Search Proxy</title>
<script type='text/javascript' src='//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js'></script>
<script>
$(function() {
  $("#search").on("submit",function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $.get('searchproxy.php', 
     {url:$("#url").val()}, 
       function(data){
         $(data).html('#result');
     });
  });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div>
<form id="search">
<input id="url" type="text" value="" />
</form>
<div id="result"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

---

```
<?php
$url = $url = $_GET["url"]; // you need to add input cleaning
$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$curl_scraped_page = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
echo $curl_scraped_page;
?>
```

Comment: Im getting 'missing name in function' error when I put it in JsFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/4ZBEf/

Comment: Also your fiddle has no html and is not running jQuery

Comment: But how do I relate this to the PHP code.. If I remove the URL part($url = 'https://www.google.nl/search?q=cars';) it doesn't work..

Comment: I mean something like this `$url = TheUrl();`

Comment: It doesn't work for me..Could the problem be `parent.document.body).val()` I would really appreciate help with this lat bit..

Comment: Without the HTML I of course have no idea. If the input field is on the same page, just do `{url:$("#inputId").val()}`

Comment: I got it to work. I don't know what was wrong in the first place. Although I did find out the url has to be really specific. For instance this doesn't work: https://google.com/  But this one does: https://www.google.nl/ So maybe I was inputting invalid urls. Anyway THANK you very much I could have never solved this one on my own, latrs(:

Comment: Thank you very much, also for input cleaning(: